# I am unable to install ggplot in rstudio using the command install.packages, how do I fix this?

Tags: rstudio

I was unable to install ggplot in studio using install packages. The rstudio console shows me the below error:

```
> install.packages('ggplot2', dep=TRUE)
Warning in install.packages("ggplot2", dep = TRUE) :
'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.13.1/library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("ggplot2", dep = TRUE) : 
unable to install packages
```

Does anyone know why this happened?

Comment: Does this issue just appear with ggplot2? In general, restart R completely and try again